# llvmlite / numba compile: g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wcovered-switch-default’

Tags: python, numba

Trying to compile llvmlite or numba from [https://github.com/numba](https://github.com/numba/) I am getting

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wcovered-switch-default’
```

any help on how to fix this would be most appreciated.
- mark

Comment: It's because llvm was compiled with clang using this option (while gcc doesn't support it) - it tries to compile llvmlite with the same options as llvm. I took the approach of recompiling llvm with gcc (but you may not want to do that - it's a bit of a hassle). I suspect compling llvmlite with clang would also work, but I don't immediately know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/numba/numba/wiki/Build-0.33-on-ubuntu-16.04 for a solution: basically make sure to the use the llvm that comes with the distribution:

```
apt-get install llvm-3.9
export LLVM_CONFIG=$(which llvm-config-3.9)
```

=> will work ok

Why? its beause the llvm that you can downlaod from http://llvm.org was built with clang, whereas the one that comes with the distribuiotn was built with g++ (I think)