# Error: Unknown CMake command "add_llvm_loadable_module"

Tags: cmake, llvm

I successfully built LLVM (v9.0.1) but, when I try to configure (via cmake) an app with it:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/APP -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86
```

I'm getting the error:

> CMake Error at examples/analyzer-plugin/CMakeLists.txt:2
>   (add_llvm_loadable_module):   Unknown CMake command
>   "add_llvm_loadable_module".

The full error log reads:

> Performing C SOURCE FILE Test
>   C_SUPPORTS_WERROR_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY_NEW failed with the following
>   output: Change Dir:
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_5d0e0/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_5d0e0.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5d0e0.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building C
>   object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5d0e0.dir/src.c.o /usr/bin/gcc   -fPIC
>   -Werror=date-time -DC_SUPPORTS_WERROR_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY_NEW   -Werror -Werror=unguarded-availability-new -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5d0e0.dir/src.c.o   -c
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c cc1:
>   error: -Werror=unguarded-availability-new: no option
>   -Wunguarded-availability-new CMakeFiles/cmTC_5d0e0.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5d0e0.dir/src.c.o' failed make[1]:
>   *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_5d0e0.dir/src.c.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_5d0e0/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_5d0e0/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: int main(void) { return 0; } Performing C++ SOURCE
>   FILE Test CXX_SUPPORTS_WERROR_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY_NEW failed with
>   the following output: Change Dir:
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_5cfc9/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_5cfc9.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5cfc9.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building
>   CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5cfc9.dir/src.cxx.o /usr/bin/g++    -fPIC
>   -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=date-time -DCXX_SUPPORTS_WERROR_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY_NEW   -Werror -Werror=unguarded-availability-new -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5cfc9.dir/src.cxx.o -c
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
>   cc1plus: error: -Werror=unguarded-availability-new: no option
>   -Wunguarded-availability-new CMakeFiles/cmTC_5cfc9.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5cfc9.dir/src.cxx.o' failed
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_5cfc9.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1 make[1]:
>   Leaving directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_5cfc9/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_5cfc9/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: int main() { return 0; } Performing C SOURCE FILE
>   Test C_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG failed with the following
>   output: Change Dir:
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_6b715/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_6b715.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_6b715.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building C
>   object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6b715.dir/src.c.o /usr/bin/gcc   -fPIC
>   -Werror=date-time -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -DC_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG   -Werror -Wcovered-switch-default -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6b715.dir/src.c.o   -c /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c gcc:
>   error: unrecognized command line option '-Wcovered-switch-default';
>   did you mean '-Wno-switch-default'?
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_6b715.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_6b715.dir/src.c.o' failed make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_6b715.dir/src.c.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_6b715/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_6b715/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: int main(void) { return 0; } Performing C++ SOURCE
>   FILE Test CXX_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG failed with the
>   following output: Change Dir:
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_e80a6/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_e80a6.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e80a6.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building
>   CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e80a6.dir/src.cxx.o /usr/bin/g++    -fPIC
>   -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=date-time -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -DCXX_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG   -Werror -Wcovered-switch-default -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e80a6.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx g++:
>   error: unrecognized command line option '-Wcovered-switch-default';
>   did you mean '-Wno-switch-default'?
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_e80a6.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_e80a6.dir/src.cxx.o' failed make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_e80a6.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving
>   directory '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_e80a6/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_e80a6/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: int main() { return 0; } Performing C++ SOURCE FILE
>   Test CXX_SUPPORTS_CLASS_MEMACCESS_FLAG failed with the following
>   output: Change Dir:
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_16b91/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_16b91.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_16b91.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building
>   CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_16b91.dir/src.cxx.o /usr/bin/g++    -fPIC
>   -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=date-time -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -DCXX_SUPPORTS_CLASS_MEMACCESS_FLAG   -Wclass-memaccess -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_16b91.dir/src.cxx.o -c
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx g++:
>   error: unrecognized command line option '-Wclass-memaccess'
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_16b91.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_16b91.dir/src.cxx.o' failed make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_16b91.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving
>   directory '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_16b91/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_16b91/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: int main() { return 0; } Performing C SOURCE FILE
>   Test C_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG failed with the following
>   output: Change Dir:
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_9c30d/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c30d.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c30d.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building C
>   object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c30d.dir/src.c.o /usr/bin/gcc   -fPIC
>   -Werror=date-time -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -DC_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG   -Werror -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c30d.dir/src.c.o   -c /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c cc1:
>   error: command line option '-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor' is valid for
>   C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror] cc1: all warnings being treated as
>   errors CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c30d.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c30d.dir/src.c.o' failed make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_9c30d.dir/src.c.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_9c30d/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_9c30d/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: int main(void) { return 0; } Performing C SOURCE FILE
>   Test C_WCOMMENT_ALLOWS_LINE_WRAP failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_1d19d/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d19d.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d19d.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building C
>   object CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d19d.dir/src.c.o /usr/bin/gcc   -fPIC
>   -Werror=date-time -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -DC_WCOMMENT_ALLOWS_LINE_WRAP  -Werror -Wcomment   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d19d.dir/src.c.o   -c
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c:1:1:
>   error: multi-line comment [-Werror=comment]  // \  ^ cc1: all warnings
>   being treated as errors CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d19d.dir/build.make:65:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d19d.dir/src.c.o' failed make[1]:
>   *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d19d.dir/src.c.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_1d19d/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_1d19d/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: // \ // int main() {return 0;} Performing C SOURCE
>   FILE Test C_SUPPORTS_STRING_CONVERSION_FLAG failed with the following
>   output: Change Dir:
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_04657/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_04657.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_04657.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building C
>   object CMakeFiles/cmTC_04657.dir/src.c.o /usr/bin/gcc   -fPIC
>   -Werror=date-time -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-comment -DC_SUPPORTS_STRING_CONVERSION_FLAG   -Werror -Wstring-conversion -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_04657.dir/src.c.o   -c
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c gcc:
>   error: unrecognized command line option '-Wstring-conversion'; did you
>   mean '-Wint-conversion'? CMakeFiles/cmTC_04657.dir/build.make:65:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_04657.dir/src.c.o' failed make[1]:
>   *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_04657.dir/src.c.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_04657/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_04657/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: int main(void) { return 0; } Performing C++ SOURCE
>   FILE Test CXX_SUPPORTS_STRING_CONVERSION_FLAG failed with the
>   following output: Change Dir:
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_82bfe/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_82bfe.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_82bfe.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building
>   CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_82bfe.dir/src.cxx.o /usr/bin/g++    -fPIC
>   -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=date-time -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-noexcept-type -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -DCXX_SUPPORTS_STRING_CONVERSION_FLAG   -Werror -Wstring-conversion -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_82bfe.dir/src.cxx.o -c
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx g++:
>   error: unrecognized command line option '-Wstring-conversion'; did you
>   mean '-Wint-conversion'? CMakeFiles/cmTC_82bfe.dir/build.make:65:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_82bfe.dir/src.cxx.o' failed
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_82bfe.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1 make[1]:
>   Leaving directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_82bfe/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_82bfe/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: int main() { return 0; } Determining if the
>   os_signpost_interval_begin exist failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_aa3b1/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_aa3b1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_aa3b1.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building C
>   object CMakeFiles/cmTC_aa3b1.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o /usr/bin/gcc
>   -fPIC -Werror=date-time -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-comment -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_aa3b1.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:2:10:
>   fatal error: os/signpost.h: No such file or directory  #include
>   
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. CMakeFiles/cmTC_aa3b1.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_aa3b1.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o' failed make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_aa3b1.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1 make[1]:
>   Leaving directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_aa3b1/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_aa3b1/fast] Error 2
>
> File
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
>   /* */
>   include  int main(int argc, char** argv) {   (void)argv;
>   ifndef os_signpost_interval_begin   return ((int*)(&os_signpost_interval_begin))[argc]; #else   (void)argc;   return 0; #endif } Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG failed with the following
>   output: Change Dir:
>   /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_d2682/fast && /usr/bin/make -f
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2682.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2682.dir/build
>   make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp' Building
>   CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2682.dir/src.cxx.o /usr/bin/g++    -fPIC
>   -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Werror=date-time -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-noexcept-type -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-strict-aliasing -pedantic -Wno-long-long -DCXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG   -Werror -Wnested-anon-types -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2682.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx g++:
>   error: unrecognized command line option '-Wnested-anon-types'; did you
>   mean '-Wnested-externs'? CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2682.dir/build.make:65:
>   recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2682.dir/src.cxx.o' failed
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2682.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1 make[1]:
>   Leaving directory
>   '/home/ubuntu/FLANG/flang-driver/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>   Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_d2682/fast' failed make: ***
>   [cmTC_d2682/fast] Error 2
>
> Source file was: int main() { return 0; }

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the **full** CMake build log, including the complete error message, not only the snippet. In addition, it would be helpful to know *where* you run this `cmake` command from.

Comment: Hi @ **squareskittles**. Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier. The log is 800+ lines long, should I post the whole thing or just the last block (about 10 lines)? The command is run from $HOME/APP/build.

Comment: I meant that the ful log is 800+ lines; the error log is 232 lines.

Comment: Ok, the error log might suffice, but essentially would be helpful to see if CMake found everything it required. Specifically looking for NOT FOUND errors

Comment: I don't see any NOT FOUND error so I'll post the error log.

Comment: Did you see the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35795582/3987854), it may apply to your situation also.

Comment: I compiled LLVM along with clang from source so the system actually used the GNU compilers. The problem might originate because of installing everything at /opt/LLVM (which would be my preference). When I pass along LLVM_CONFIG=/opt/LLVM, the new error states "llvm-config failed with status Permission denied." I still have to check if there is any way around this issue or if the only solution is to redo the installation (which takes several hours) and install everything in the default directory.

Comment: You have built `llvm` but for your app you are using `gcc/g++`. llvm cmake ecosystem was not initialized correctly for your app that's why the macro you are trying to use not found, or as it can be seen in llvm cmake files this macro was deleted and you try to use undefined macro.

Comment: I also tried building the app with clang but it failed (the app website states that it's easier to build with gcc/g++ than with clang/clang++). I'm trying to understand what you mean by the wrong initialization or that the macro was deleted (if the latter happened, it was definitely unintentional and I'm not sure what caused it). How would you initialize the llvm/cmake ecosystem correctly? I simply compiled with clang a very simple code.